# Redirect based on a URL rather than an IP address in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I use a redirect in .htaccess to redirect any user asking for domain.com/admin to domain.com as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^101.101.101.101
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

This redirects all visitors other than those coming from the fictional IP address `101.101.101.101`  and it works fine.

I want to be able to replace the IP address with a URL like `abc.domain.com` as the IP address `101.101.101.101` can vary over time and a dynamic DNS has been set up at `abc.domain.com` to track the updated IP address. Is this possible?

I have tried putting the URL in single quotes, double quotes, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.from_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.to_domain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^101.101.101.101
```

With this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?abc\.domain\.com$
```

Clear browser cache then test , if it is OK , replace `R=302` to `R=301` to be permenant redirection.